# circular reference in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
$('#save').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // preventing default click action
    $.ajax({
        url: '/share',
        type: 'post',
        contentType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            title: $('#title'),
            body: $('#body'),
            status: 'Published'
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#{{ form.share_id.name }}').val(data.id);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Can somebody tell me how the above json stringify leads to circular reference ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is because you are trying to stringify an object having dom element references.... dom elements have circular references because an element will have references to its children and parent.

I think what you might want is to have the contents of the said elements `#title` and `#body`

```
$('#save').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // preventing default click action
    $.ajax({
        url: '/share',
        type: 'post',
        contentType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            title: $('#title').text(),
            body: $('#body').text(),
            status: 'Published'
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#{{ form.share_id.name }}').val(data.id);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid circular reference use text method for text() instead of sending that DOM element

```
//JSON.stringify({
//           title: $('#title'),
//            body: $('#body'),
//            status: 'Published'
//        }),

JSON.stringify({
            title: $('#title').text(),
            body: $('#body').text(),
            status: 'Published'
        }),
```